Does Swift have a "varalias" like "typealias"?
Is there a "variable name alias" like there is a "typealias"?  I'd like to be able to access my model by just the member name (it's a simple toy-view learning sample).  So something like
var m : contentViewModel {@Published var content : String}

varalias content = m.content

Button {content = "Sample"}


Short answer. No
